# ASP.NET Cookies weird error

Tags: asp.net

On my site i did "remember me" once login on my admin account, and than i did logout(It deletes cookie once you logout) and i wanted to enter with another account and checking " remember me", and i get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpCookie' to type 'System.String'.
```

I think it input some weird thing on my Session but i have no idea why..

What i have tried already:
I have tried already everything, and i have no idea why it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to fix?
Thanks.

here code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.Cookies["account"] != null)
        {
            Session["user2"] = Request.Cookies["userFont"];
            Session["user"] = Request.Cookies["account"];
        }

        if (Session["user"] == null)
        {
            Session["user2"] = "Guest";
            hey = (string)Session["user2"];
            log += "You are not logged in, <a href='Login.aspx'><font color='red'>Log in!</font></a> or <a href='Register.aspx'><font color='red'>Register!</font></a> ";
            button += "<td><a href='Login.aspx' class='button'>Log in</a></td>";
        }
        else
        {
            hi = (string)Session["user"];
          hey = "<a href='\\Profile.aspx?user="+hi+"'>" + Session["user2"] + "</a>";
            button += "<td><a href='Login.aspx' class='button'>Log out</a></td>";
        }
```

i am getting error on:

```
hi = (string)Session["user"];
```

Comment: Please locate (and show it here) the code that you have this error.

Comment: Show code? He has tried everything.

Comment: Are you trying to set `hi` to the value of your cookie? If so, try `hi = ((System.Web.HttpCookie)Session["user"]).Value;`

Comment: I am getting, Welcome System.Web.HttpCookie
and it supposed to be Welcome Name(name of your account).

Answer (score 1):

This here `Session["user"] = Request.Cookies["account"];` sets a cookie not a string.
Use `((HttpCookie)Session["user"]).Value;` to get your string back from the Cookie.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx

Comment: ((HttpCookie)Session["user"]).Value = Request.Cookies["account"];

I get error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpCookie' to 'string' s

Comment: You mixed up my answer. The left side of your code is how you should read a cookie - you try to set data there...